OpenID Connect Exceptions not using UseExceptionHandler middleware
Currently looking into the odd failure in one of our ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC websites you maybe able to help with.
To prefix, authentication works fine 99% of the time, however as shown in screenshot #1, if an exception were to occur during OnTokenValidated, how do we get this exception on the general error page?
We've setup the OnAuthenticationFailed handler, where we can get this exception via ticket.Exception, however I can't seem to find documentation that will make use of the general error page configured by the UseExceptionHandler middleware (screenshot #2), thus leveraging the IExceptionHandlerPathFeature abstraction in the ErrorViewModel (screenshot #3).
The best we're able to do is redirect in the OnAuthenticationFailed and log the exception there.
Any help would be appreciated



Edit:
To simplify the problem, here an example of what's happening -

Exception is thrown in the OnValidatedToken handler
OnAuthenticationFailed is called (presumably the middleware catches our exception and calls this)
We have access to the exception via ticket.Exception here, however at this step we're unsure of how to get this to the UseExceptionHandler middlware that would then both redirect to our /Main/Error page and provide the IExceptionHandlerPathFeature to our model.



How about throw other simple exceptions?

How do you mean? where? how would this help me get the ExceptionHandlerPathFeature set to then be used in the ErrorViewModel on the Error page?

If you throw an error like "ticket.Fail("test");", it will turn to error page. But the this.authenticated seems not throw a true exception. Could you share the code of this.Authenticated?

@QiangFu I'll edit the question to include a reproducable example but just a normal exception thrown - ticket.Fail does not seem to get the user redirected to the Error page in either the OnTokenValidated or OnAuthenticationFailed

I think you also need to post the "Main/Error"endpoint code. The default is "Home/Errror" which is always being called in my test.
